# In FoxPro, data session window lost

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

Normally, I can use the command "SET" to view the Data Session window. The window doesn't show up anymore, even if I use the menus under Windows -> Data Session.  I think I lost the window off the edge of the screen. How can I get it back?

Answer (score 2):

Do this in the command window

```
SET                         && make the window active
MOVE WINDOW "View" TO 1,1   && move it to location 1,1
```